# Can I call destructor for a class member, which is an object using dynamic memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, destructor

If I have the following classes:

```cpp
class Small {
public:
    Small();
    Small(const Small &small);
    ~Small();
private:
    int *arr;
};
```

and

```cpp
class Big {
public:
    Big();
    Big(const Big &big);
    ~Big();
private:
    char *name;
    Small smallObject;
};
```

When I call `~Big()` I delete the dynamic memory, allocated for the `name` member, but `smallObject` also uses dynamic memory, which I don't free.
When I try something like

```cpp
Big::~Big() {
    delete[] this->name;
    this->smallObject.~Small();
}
```

I get an error (because there is no such syntax). How does one free the dynamic memory, allocated to `smallObject`?

Comment: You shouldn't, what's the problem actually, which makes you think you should? (the syntax problem seems to stem from operator precedence). `SmallObject` should free the memory it allocates itself.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I haven't called the destructor for the object `smallObject` explicitly and I thought I should (in order to avoid memory leaks).

Comment: The `smallObject` member will be automatically deleted when any `Big` object is deleted. But are you, rather, concerned about deleting the `arr` member of `Small`?

Comment: See my latest edit. Each class should be resposible for the memory it allocates dynamically itself. @DanielHalachev

Comment: the general rule is: 1. for each `new` you issue, you must issue a `delete`. No need to called destructor dierectly.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, I was worried that the dynamic array `arr` of `smallObject` won't be deleted If I didn't call the `~Small()` destructor explicitly.

Comment: As long as your `Small` destructor frees that memory, you're fine. Because `smallObject` is an actual object (not a pointer), the destructor will be called automatically when any containing `Big` is deleted.

Comment: Alright. Thank you all!

Comment: @DanielHalachev _"array arr of smallObject won't be deleted If I didn't call the ~Small() destructor explicitly."_ As mentioned, that needs to be handled in `SmallObject`'s destructor, not by the class using it. The destructor will be called automatically if `Big` is destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever the destructor for a composite object such as `Big` completes, it automatically calls the destructors for all member and base objects, so you don't want to call such destrutors explicitly.  If you did, the object destructor would be called twice, which would cause problems.

So in this case, the `Big` destructor will automatically call the `Small` destructor, and, assuming that deletes the pointer (or whatever else needs to be done to clean up Small::arr), there should be no leak.

Note that the "destructors" for `name` and `arr` will also be called, but as those fields are pointers, the destructors are noops.

One possible way this could leak is if the destructor were to exit with an exception -- this is (part of) why destructors should never throw exceptions; dealing with them is painful and error prone.

Comment: You should add a comment for `Small` to init, alloc and free `arr`

Comment: Great! Thank you!